# ¿Cómo buscar contenido de un objeto dentro de un ArrayList?

Tags: java

Cordial saludo,

Tengo una duda, quiero buscar la String codigo que pertenece al objeto Producto el cual se crea dentro de una ArrayList. Cómo podria hacerlo?

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {

      ArrayList<Producto> products = new ArrayList<>();

                                  //codigo,cantidad,precio
        products.add(new Producto("0034",2,300));
        products.add(new Producto("0325",3,100));
        products.add(new Producto("0235",1,50));
        products.add(new Producto("1454",1,600));
        products.add(new Producto("6234",1,900));
        products.add(new Producto("8424",6,200));
        products.add(new Producto("0279",4,400));
        products.add(new Producto("0036",3,100));
        products.add(new Producto("0234",1,40));
        products.add(new Producto("0313",2,350));

}
```

Por ejemplo quisiera encontrar el codigo 0313, dentro del ArrayList. He intentado con indexOf, pero al ser el Array de tipo objeto no me ha encontrado un valor especifico. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias reccorer el AraryList con un for y dentro un condicional que campare cada objeto
del tal forma que podrias tener algo tipo:

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < products.size() ; i ++){
               Condicional           
    }
```

recuerda que puedes usar metodos del ArrayList como products.get(i) que retorna lo que este dentro del indice "i" y puedes añadir metodos de la misma clase Productos como products.get(i).getCodigo()

Espero ayudarte con esto.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Me lo solucionó perfectamente. El código quedó así: for(int i=0; i<products.size();i++){

        if (products.get(i).getCodigo().equals("0313")){
          System.out.println(products.get(i));
        }

Answer (score 1):

Crea un metodo el cual retorna el item que necesitas y busque por el campo que necesites.

por ejemplo:

```java
Product getProduct(ArrayList<Product> productos, String key){
  for(Producto item: productos){
    if(item.getCodigo()==key) return item;
  }
  return null;
}
```

El cual retornara null si no encuentra el producto.

La otra opcion y mas optima es usar un `HashMap` en el cual puedes usar el metodo `get` y va a buscar por la clave asignada, por si tienes dudas te dejo un link con informacion a `HashMap`

[Documentacion HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> Disculpas por los acentos no tengo teclado en espanol :(

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha servido mucho para aprender un nuevo tema que son los HashMap